# Rolling available Calculation

Tags: excel-formula, rolling-computation

What I think I am looking for is a rolling calculation, for example:

```
If A2 = F2:F4 Then subtract B2 from G2 and add C2 with result in D2. This would continue until it reaches the same part again like in rows 3,4,8,and 10. Once a part is repeated rather than looking at the column G I would like it to use the latest value in D. 
A3 = F2:F4 subtract B3 from G3 and add C3 with result in D3 (20-5+0-15)
A4 = F2:F4 subtract B4 from D4 and add C4 with result in D4 (15-2+0-13)
A8 = F2:F4 subtract B8 from D8 and add C8 with result in D8 (13-8+7-12)
A10 = F2:F4 subtract B10 from D10 and add C10 with result in D10 (12-2+0-10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use VLOOKUP to return the correct start, and SUMIFS with dynamic range to do the subtraction and addition.

```
=VLOOKUP([@PART],Table3,2,FALSE)-SUMIFS($B$2:B2,$A$2:A2,[@PART])+SUMIFS($C$2:C2,$A$2:A2,[@PART])
```

[image]

Note: to use only structured references we need to introduce the volatile OFFSET:

```
=VLOOKUP([@PART],Table3,2,FALSE)-
    SUMIFS(OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[QTY]],1,,ROW()-ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[QTY]])),OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[PART]],1,,ROW()-ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[PART]])),[@PART])+
    SUMIFS(OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[DELIVERED QTY]],1,,ROW()-ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[DELIVERED QTY]])),OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[PART]],1,,ROW()-ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[PART]])),[@PART])
```